# How to define C macro for list of global struct variable

Tags: c, macros, global-variables

While I am help contributing to https://github.com/cilium/cilium/issues/20692 that the idea is to declare all these structs as global variable outside of main(), here is what I could come up with https://github.com/cilium/cilium/issues/20692#issuecomment-1209554992, how to write a macro to represent **struct foo a;**, **struct bar b;**...etc.?

```
diff --git a/bpf/bpf_alignchecker.c b/bpf/bpf_alignchecker.c
index 46f5e1b7b2..0d6cec466d 100644
--- a/bpf/bpf_alignchecker.c
+++ b/bpf/bpf_alignchecker.c
@@ -32,17 +32,21 @@
  * to the var to a BPF helper function which accepts a reference as
  * an argument.
  */
+/*
 #define DECLARE(type)                  \
 {                                      \
        type s = {};                    \
        trace_printk("%p", 1, &s);      \
 }
-
+*/
 /* This function is a placeholder for C struct definitions shared with Go,
  * it is never executed.
  */
+struct ipv4_ct_tuple a;
+struct ipv6_ct_tuple b;
+struct blabla...continue;

 int main(void)
 {
+       /*
        DECLARE(struct ipv4_ct_tuple);
        DECLARE(struct ipv6_ct_tuple);
        DECLARE(struct ct_entry);
@@ -94,6 +98,7 @@ int main(void)
        DECLARE(struct srv6_vrf_key6);
        DECLARE(struct srv6_policy_key4);
        DECLARE(struct srv6_policy_key6);
+       */
 
        return 0;
 }
```

or to put the question in simple way, if I have

```
struct ipv4_ct_tuple a;
struct ipv6_ct_tuple b;
struct ct_entry c;
struct ipcache_key d;
struct remote_endpoint_info e;
struct lb4_key f;
struct lb4_service g;
struct lb4_backend h;

main() {
   return 0;
}
```

how do I write a macro and use the macro to replace each **struct foo a**

more background:

all these structs are defined in various header files included in https://github.com/cilium/cilium/blob/master/bpf/bpf_alignchecker.c#L13-L27, the sole purpose of  bpf_alignchecker.c is to check alignment match between C and Golang structs based on BPF BTF debug info compiled in  bpf_aligncheck.o, and bpf_alignment.o  is not linked to any executable program, we don't need to worry about any program execution. now the problem is bpf_alignchecker.o does not include BTF debug info of the structs because the clang compiler requires these structs to be global variable to bpf_alignchecker.o.

Comment: See my answer: [Dynamically populate struct in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72904245/5382650)

Comment: it is kind of beyond my understanding with your solution, i am not sure it addresses what i am asking or maybe I did not describe my problem clearly :). my goal is not to waste variable a, b, c.. for each struct, just repeat a macro for each struct like original DECLARE macro https://github.com/cilium/cilium/blob/master/bpf/bpf_alignchecker.c#L35, but make each struct as global variable

Comment: Not knowing the background of this, it's hard to guess. You can always have a script that reads standard definitions and generates a file (vs. using macros). I've done many of these. How about: `#define DECLARE(_type) \
 struct _type _type##_global;

#define ALLSTRUCT(_cmd) \
 _cmd(ipv4_ct_tuple) \
 _cmd(ipv6_ct_tuple) \
 _cmd(ct_entry) \
 _cmd(ipcache_key) \
 _cmd(remote_endpoint_info) \
 _cmd(lb4_key) \
 _cmd(lb4_service) \
 _cmd(lb4_backend)

ALLSTRUCT(DECLARE)`

Comment: If you can edit your question and describe what you have (e.g. a `.h` that has struct definitions) and what you want: A file that produces a global instance of each definition found?

Comment: I re-edited my post to add more background to explain the situation, is your above macro suggestion going to work? I could try at least :)

Comment: Still a little unsure, but _if_ you want to do what you do in `bfp_alignchecker.c` (e.g. enumerate all struct defs to produce _globals_), then my version of the macro should work. Just put the `ALLSTRUCT(DECLARE)` at global scope as I've done. This will generate (e.g.) `struct foo foo_global;` for any "foo" that is part of `ALLSTRUCT`. Note that every time a new struct is defined, you'll have to add it [manually] to the `ALLSTRUCT` macro (vs. writing a script that parses the `.h` files to generate the `.c` file). You were generating function scope vars and you need global!?

Comment: thanks, I will hold on your answer and see if any input from the cilium upstream devs on the macro.